# Querying XML with unique entry using XPath Java returns nothing

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I'm attempting to retrieve the value of a single element in an XML file. I've truncated the XML to the relevant bit:

```
<opt>
    <security>
        <check>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </check>
    </security>
</opt>
```

I'm trying to retrieve 'true' from the 'secure' element.

I have the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder=domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(file);

XPath xpath=XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr=xpath.compile("//opt/security/check/secure/text()");

Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
logger.warn(result.toString());
```

I'm just trying to get any value for now, and I'll change the String to Boolean once I get this to work.

My output is blank, I've tried a bunch of different things, including following a tutorial and using NodeLists (although that didn't make very much sense to me since this is a unique element). Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Clearly this is a namespace issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works using the default XPath implementation in my JVM (Sun/Oracle Java on Windows):

```
>java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

The double forward-slash isn't necessary in the sample document; as [MSDN notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256199.aspx):

> An expression that uses the double forward slash (//) indicates a search that can include zero or more levels of hierarchy.

I wonder if this is a namespace issue:

```
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

You could try omitting this line or [providing a NamespaceContext](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-using-xpath-with-namespaces-and.html).

Comment: Omitting worked like a charm, I could have sworn I tried removing it before. Also, I didn't declare any namespaces either (which begs the question of why I was using NamespaceAware, I guess). Anyway, **thanks a lot!**

Comment: +1 For not starting `//` operator when the schema is well known. I think you should quote XPath spec instead of MSDN... -1 for `setNamespaceAware(false);`: if you are going to work with XML you need to know XML...